# Ruby Regex: parsing C++ classes

Tags: ruby, regex

I am curious about parsing C++ code using regexp. What I have so far (using ruby) allows me to extract class declarations and their parent classes (if any):

```
/(struct|class)\s+([^{:\s]+)\s*[:]?([^{]+)\s*\{/
```

Here is an [example](http://rubular.com/r/Q6tBiC8iTU) in Rubular. Notice I can capture correctly the "declaration" and "inheritance" parts.

The point at where I am stuck is at capturing the class **body**. If I use the following extension of the original regex:

```
/(struct|class)\s+([^{:\s]+)\s*[:]?([^{]+)\s*\{[^}]*\};/
```

Then I can capture the class body *only if* it does not contain any curly braces, and therefore any class or function definition. 
At this point I have tried many things but none of them make this better. 
For instance, if I include in the regexp the fact that the body can contain braces, it will capture the first class declaration and then all the subsequent classes as if they were part of the first class' body!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [group capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) might help:

```
#                   named  v    backref          v
/(struct|class)\s+(?<match>{((\g<match>|[^{}]*))*})/m
```

Here we find the *matching* curly bracket for the one following `struct`/`class` declaration. You probably will want to tune the regexp, I posted this to make the solution as clear as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not the recommended way to parse code.

Most compilers and interpreters use [lexers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and parsers to convert code into an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) before compiling or running the code.

Ruby has a few lexer gems, like [this](https://github.com/chriswailes/RLTK), you can try and incorporate into your project.

Comment: In general, this is correct. In some cases however, a regexp might be just "good enough". E.g. for a quick, heuristic analysis of some code.

Comment: @undur_gongor - stating the OP's first sentence - "I am curious about parsing C++ code using regexp" - this sounds as general as they come :). I do agree that for some tasks reading HTML or code using regexp is sufficient, as long as the code is not arbitrary (you exactly where is comes from, and how it is constructed)

Comment: Thanks Uri. Although your answer seems quite enlightening, I was only "playing" with the possibilities of parsing c++ code (e.g. counting the number of methods in a class, etc). I will accept mudasobwa's answer as it helped me a lot, but keeping your valuable advice in mind ;)

Comment: Thanks Uri. Although your answer seems quite enlightening, I was only "playing" with the possibilities of parsing c++ code (e.g. counting the number of methods in a class, etc). I will accept mudasobwa's answer as it helped me a lot, but keeping your valuable advice in mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

What I can offer you is this:

```
(struct|class)\s+([^{:\s]+)\s*[:]?([^{]+)\{([^{}]|\{\g<4>\})*\};
```

Where `\g<4>` is a recursive application of the fourth capture group, which is `([^{}]|\{\g<4>\})`.

Matching non-regular languages with regular expressions is never pretty. You might want to consider switching to a proper recursive descent parser, especially if you plan to do something with the stuff you just captured.